# pg_hba.conf entry for host "103.244.174.70", user "postgres", database "patientlist", no encryption, when connecting to db from nodejs sequelize-auto

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "103.244.174.70", user "postgres", database "patientlist", no encryption
    at Client._connectionCallback (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\connection-manager.js:143:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:327:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:347:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:117:12
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9) {
  parent: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "103.244.174.70", user "postgres", database "patientlist", no encryption
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hamza\nx gen\patient record system\backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)
```

getting this error and not being able to find a solution using the solutions provided on the internet

tried almost every solution and still getting this error

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to try "solutions provided on the internet". What you need to do is go to the official manuals and type "pg_hba.conf" into the handy search-box.

That will take you to [the page on pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) which explains what the entries mean and when the file gets reloaded. Having read and understood that page you can open up the correct access.

Note: I hope that IP address is on a private network, because you probably don't want to be exposing access as the postgres user (or if possible any other) to the public internet.

Answer (score 0):

add below lines in pg_hba.conf file

```
hostnossl    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            scram-sha-256
```

this will resolved your issue